# How to retrieve a session name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, redis

In python 3.7 I run a code that tries to connect to a Redis instance on another machine, that has no password. Basically the code does:

```
sess = redis.get("<ipaddr>", password=None)
name = sess.get("session_name")
```

However, the last command returns None. Is there another string I should use instead of `"session_name"` to retrieve the session name? I am using Redis 3.4.1.

Comment: Can you use `redis-cli` to check whether the redis-server has the key `session_name`?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't... Is there some way to retrieve it without accessing the cli? Perhaps with some one-liner?